# "Holes" discovered in the Milky Way Galaxy

Tags: galaxy

Recently I read that Astronomers have noticed a few "holes" in our Galaxy. They are about one million times the mass of our Sun. They are baffled as to what could have caused this and speculate that perhaps it was done by Dark Matter. My question is, what happened with any Stars and Planets in this region ? Would they have been pushed aside or destroyed by this event ?

Comment: A volume with a diameter a million times the diameter of the sun is less than a quarter of a light year across. Astronomers are unlikely to notice such holes. Where does your information come from?

Comment: @BMF For Monica This information comes from  Ana Bonaca, a researcher at the Harvard Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look into it to see if I can answer. Edit: it appears that by *size* you mean *mass* (at least, reading from the first article I clicked on). That is, the holes aren't a million times the size of the sun. Whatever phenomena created the holes are suspected to have a mass a million times the mass of the sun.

Comment: You should add a link to an article about this.  Google draws up several using the name and details provided, such as https://www.livescience.com/65483-dark-impactor-could-be-dark-matter.html   I'd add this directly to your post myself but I haven't read through it enough to know if it effectively answers your question already; you may have been reading form a different source that gave different impressions.

Comment: Could you add a source for your information?  i'm anxious to read about this...

Comment: @jmh Click on the link provided by zibadawa timmy above, for more information on this topic

Comment: One every 80 square light years seems a tad over-dense for the things, to me. https://www.cnet.com/news/monster-black-hole-that-should-not-exist-discovered-in-the-milky-way/

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger but the topic concerns dark matter, why are you bringing Black Holes into it ? What does one have to do with the other ?

Comment: @PeterU Oh dear. Two different mysterious hole types reported at same time. -Sorry.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger No problem, actually what my question is, whether these Stars and Planets that used to be where the hole is now, got destroyed or pushed aside ?